# Non-integer bases and irrationality

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, number-systems

I read somewhere:

> When it comes to properties like prime, irrational, rational,
>   divisible by 2, etc., nothing changes when you change base.

But I'm not sure about the rational/irrational one.
If you use non-integer bases, even integer numbers can become ugly expressions (See 3 in base 2.5 in [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%20in%20base%202.5))
The point is: is that number irrational, or it just has a lot of repeating decimals?
Either way, how could you prove it?

Comment: You are aware that "irrational" is not defined as "has an infinite non repeating decimal expansion", right?

Comment: I was not aware. Now I am. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The distinction you are missing is that there are *numbers*, which have certain properties, and then there are *numerals*, which are sequences of symbols that we use to *represent* numbers.

The base is a choice about how to *represent* a number as a numeral.  For example, in base 10, the  *number* 100 is represented with the symbol `100`.  In base 7, it is represented as `202`; in base 13 it is represented as `79`.  In all cases, it is a perfect square; it is an even number; it is a multiple of 5, and so forth, because *it is the same number*.  It is still equal to $36+64$, regardless of whether we write that equation as `36 + 64 = 100` or as `51 + 121 = 202` or as `2A + 4C = 79`.

The only questions that change with the base have to do with the *representation*, with the particular symbols that are used to write down the numeral.  The base-10 representation of the number 100 ends with a zero, and the base-7 representation of the same number does not.  A number is divisible by 10 if and only if its base-10 numeral ends with a zero, so you can conclude that 100 is divisible by 10; it is divisible by 7 if and only if its base-7 numeral ends in a 0, and so you can conclude that 100 is not divisible by 7.

3 is a rational number and an integer, regardless of how it is written or in what base.  It is true that a rational number will have a repeating or terminating *representation* in an integer base, and an irrational number will not, but that is separate from the question of whether it is a rational number.

Writing 3 in "base $2.5$" means observing:

$$ 3 = \color{red}1\cdot 2.5 + \color{red}0\cdot 1 + \frac{\color{red}1}{2.5} + \frac{\color{red}0}{(2.5)^2} + \cdot\frac{\color{red}1}{(2.5)^3} + \cdots \\ = \color{red}{10.101\ldots}_{(2.5)} $$

but the fact that this *representation* does or doesn't repeat has nothing to do with whether the number 3 is an integer.

Comment: Very clean explanation, now I got the point. Many thanks!
P.S.: You edited your answer a lot o_o

Comment: Yes, that's the way I write. You should see the drafts of my book. I tinkered with the text for *years*.

Comment: One thing you didn't touch on that I think @Adrià Rico Blanes was asking about is that in every integer ($>2$) base the rational numbers are the ones with finite or periodic expansions and the irrational numbers are the ones with no finite/periodic expansion. The proof sketch for base 10 on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Every_rational_number_is_either_a_terminating_or_repeating_decimal) works fine for base 2, base 7, etc.

Comment: I did say "It is true that a rational number will have a repeating or terminating representation in an integer base".