# Practical use for non-integer logarithmic bases

Tags: logarithms

Are there practical uses (ie: in engineering, applied sciences, chemistry, IT, etc) for using non-integer bases?

[From other questions on the topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411238/non-integer-bases-and-irrationality), I see that it's just another way of representing numbers, but does this ever come up in practical examples? I know that taking the base-2 logarithm of a number [lets us calculate the number of entropy bits in a password](http://xkcd.com/936/), the base-10 logarithm has uses in [power calculations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel), and the natural logarithm can be used for things [like determining RC filter decay time constants](http://www.foothill.edu/~marasco/labfive/).

So, with the exception of the natural logarithm, does it ever make sense to use non-integer bases?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation   has some practical examples.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you. I had forgotten about the golden ratio and recurrence relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the function $e^x$ is extremely important and basic in all of science and so therefore so is the natural logarithm (which is log base $e$).  And of course $e$ is not an integer.

Comment: $e^x$ is the only function that is its own derivative, which is one reason it comes up so often in practical applications.

Comment: Well, I mentioned "with the exception of the natural logarithm", but between this and the comments above, I found what I was looking for. Thanks!